# What makes "Voter ID laws" so controversial in the US?

Tags: united-states, law, identity-document

As a European, I am always baffled by the concept that requiring an ID to vote is so controversial in the US, for me is one of the most "natural" things.

I hear that it is because obtaining an ID in the US in no simple matter, is it true?

What are the historical and political reasons that make the topic so controversial?

Comment: @Skooba - ID's are really easy to get if you are a legal citizen, have all the required documentation on hand, have a means of transportation to get to the place where ID applications are accepted, are able to appear during that place's business hours without losing your job, and have the financial means to pay any associated fees. FTFY

Comment: @Skooba - 1) The voter ID laws are very specific about the type of ID they will accept. The state I live in did not routinely issue birth certificates to every baby until 20 years ago. You need to request it and pay a fee.. 2) The area I live in has no public transportation. 3) Employers are less restrictive about ID. They require Social Security cards, which are not acceptable for voter ID. 4) Not everyone has a job, so your nominal fee (coupled with the cost of public transportation if available) could be unaffordable.

Comment: @Skooba most of the rural US, which is most of the US, has no public transportation.

Comment: @Skooba I'm unaware of these laws being an issue in cities.  Most of the coverage I've seen concerning disenfranchisement of poorer voters has covered the rural poor and their need to drive for hours to reach an office where they can get an ID.

Comment: @skooba your are glossing over all of the complexities. Because something is easy for you does not mean it is for everyone else.

Comment: It's controversial in the UK too. A [previous plan to introduce ID cards was abandoned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_Cards_Act_2006). In their absence, there is no form of photo ID (e.g. driving licence, passport) that everyone has.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Indeed! And we are (for now at least) also Europeans (I'm referring to the OP saying "as a European". I would be interested (thinking aloud) to what extent England, Scotland, and Wales are the odd ones out in Europe when it comes to voter ID.

Comment: I think that is a misconception. I would guess most states US states have similar documentation requirements to most EU countries (you need something that identifies you as you, but not necessarily the ID card; I would assume to prevent duplication of votes). I'm not sure but this issue seems to me to be much more about party warmongering (politics) and less about the philosophical concepts of voting and voters.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are many reasons that a voter ID requirement is controversial. This is just a list of some arguments or concerns regarding voter ID laws, there is no attempt to determine the reasonableness of any of them.

### National Identification

Elections and identification are two issues that are generally dealt with by states, not the national government. States organize elections. States issue the normal forms of identification in the United States (either a driver's license or another identification).

There is a strain of American politics that has a strong fear of the national government. Consider that all Americans do have a national (non-photo) identification in the form of a social security card. This just contains the number we need to access our national social welfare and insurance programs, as well as being a secondary form of ID in many cases.

Social security is at the center of many conspiracy theories (for example, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redemption_movement) or [this](http://www.snopes.com/business/taxes/blackssn.asp)).  The idea of a national identification card strikes many of the same fears: an oppressive national government, intrusion into private lives, etc. Many people have reasonable concerns, far from the world of conspiracy theories.

### Privacy

Some people have privacy concerns related to an identification to vote. The idea of an anonymous vote is a part of the American system. A voter ID introduces the idea that voting behavior could be tied to this ID, which would be a significant intrusion into our supposedly-anonymous elections.

The Electronics Frontier Foundation published an [article](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2016/02/voter-privacy-what-you-need-know-about-your-digital-trail-during-2016-election) summarizing many concerns about elections and privacy. If you wished to know more, I recommend their article.  According to their article, some Americans are shocked to discover that you can access voter registration lists as well as information about who voted when.

### Voter Suppression

Some people are worried that voter ID requirements are either intended to prevent people from voting, or will have the effect of preventing people from voting.  In the last 100 years, racial and economic biases in elections have been an important issue. Although African Americans were legally able to vote as early as [1870](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution), in practice many states or cities had rampant discrimination. There were monetary requirements (which poor Black farmers couldn't afford to pay), literacy tests (which largely uneducated Black citizens couldn't pass), as well as physical violence and manipulation to deter Black voters.  From these experiences, the idea of deterring a group from voting may invoke powerful feelings in many Americans.

One group that opposes voter ID requirements (including the national voter ID) is the [American Civil Liberties Union](https://www.aclu.org/other/oppose-voter-id-legislation-fact-sheet). They are concerned, as are many, that these ID laws will lower voter turnout in general, but will disproportionately affect minorities (who are less likely to have identification).

### Voter Fraud

Some people are concerned about the possibility of vote fraud, where somebody votes who shouldn't be able to. This is often tied to concerns about immigration, since it seems without an ID requirement immigrants (both legal and illegal) could vote in an American election, which they are not entitled to.

This view is espoused in many news articles ([example](http://www.thepoliticalinsider.com/virginia-voter-fraud-thousands-illegal-aliens-registered-vote/)).

Comment: Perhaps worth noting: Not *every* American has a Social Security card, or even a Social Security number - but the vast majority indeed do.

Comment: @Iszi it's also worth noting that the SSN scheme was carefully designed *from the beginning* not to be an identification scheme. The cards specifically state, or at least they used to, that they're not for identification. Obviously, efforts to prevent the use of SSNs in this way weren't particularly successful, but as identity theft becomes more of a problem the use of the SSN for unrelated purposes has in fact declined somewhat.

Comment: @Iszi - Do you have any idea how many Americans don't have SSNs? If it's a reasonable number, I would edit it in, but I can't find an estimate anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how many Americans don't have SSNs, but the issue seems to have bee notable enough to be included in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number). It's under the sub-heading "Non-universal status", and the Old Order Amish are noted as one group particularly fighting its usage.

Comment: @phoog: Wikipedia also notes the "Not For Identification" statement you refer to, and has an image of a sample card with that statement. However, it appears that has been removed - I just checked three separate cards, covering at least two revisions of the form (Form SSA-3000), and none of them have such a statement.

Comment: Normally a Social Security Card would not be used for voter ID. Sometimes a birth certificate plus a driver's license (to prove citizenship plus identity), or a naturalization certificate and a driver's license, or a passport would be used. Perhaps 5% of potential voters lack a driver's license, state ID or passport.

Comment: @ohwilleke - I think you are right about the social security card, I'm just not sure how it's relevant here.

Comment: This answer should be combined with Drunk Cynic's answer below to make a complete answer. These are indeed the arguments that are presented against voter ID, but it is incomplete (i.e. one-sided) to present them without the context in which they are made. If you asked a Democrat why the laws are controversial he would give your answer. If you asked a Republican why the laws are controversial he would say "because Democrats think it will hurt their election prospects if only legal voters vote". Both views should be represented.

Comment: @Readin That is untrue. Many Republicans are also worried about voter suppression, privacy, and voter fraud - they are in no way Democrat owned issues.  At least in my area, Republicans are largely against the national ID because of my first point.

Comment: For the most part, the ID that is required is government issued "picture ID".  So, a driver's license, a passport, a naturalization or citizenship certificate, military ID, other state-issued picture ID etc.  Birth certificates and SS Cards don't carry pictures.  They can be used as proof to get a picture ID, but they can't be used to vote.  So, if you are a 90 year-old with no birth certificate who has had their license revoked, it can get difficult to procure an appropriate ID. (my comments are based on Texas, where I live).

Comment: @Iszi it's also worth noting that hundreds of thousands of non-Americans *do* have Social Security cards, so it would be next to useless as voter ID.

Comment: @Flydog57 non only do SS cards lack pictures, but they don't prove eligibility to vote, since noncitizens can get them too.

Comment: @phoog: Other than a passport and a naturalization or citizenship certificate, none of the "acceptable" forms of photo id prove voter eligibility, they only prove identity (i.e., they provide authentication, not authorization).  Photo Ids don't keep ineligible voters from voting (say someone who fraudulently registered to vote and has a driver's license).  They prevent person A from voting using person's B identity.
It's worth noting that just about every voting violation I've ever read was from a mail-in ballot, not in-person impersonation (which would be awfully risky).

Answer (score 35):

The controversy isn't about the laws themselves. The heart of the matter is partisan concerns and attacking the 'intentions' of those on the other side.

The leading arguments for ID's come from the Republican party, with the belief that ID's would ensure the veracity of claims at the voting both and elsewhere. The concept of people fraudulently voting, subverting the Rule of Law and the established processes of these United States, is unsettling. The ugliest side of the argument claims that Democrats want as many [fraudulent voters](http://www.rightwingwatch.org/post/glenn-grothman-joins-other-republicans-in-admitting-voter-id-laws-are-about-suppressing-democratic-voters/) as [possible](http://thedailybanter.com/2016/04/another-republican-admitted-that-voter-id/), ensuring they win future elections.

The leading arguments against ID's come from the Democratic party, with the belief that ID's places an undue burden on the poor, those born as US citizens without documentation, and is an echo of the Poll taxes from Jim Crow. The concept of disenfranchising people, violating their natural rights, is unsettling. The ugliest side of this argument claims that Republicans hate people that aren't white, so if they can invalidate as many of their votes as possible, it will ensure Republican victory.

An external argument from those of the Libertarian mind, whether left or right on the ideological spectrum, see the continued use of ID's as detrimental to rights overall. If the government can force you to present your 'papers,' in a Nazi-esque fashion, they can curtail your freedom to move freely about the country.

Comment: With respect to freedom of movement, this argument depends on the assumption that a requirement to present ID at the poll site will evolve into checking IDs elsewhere.  That assumption is perhaps a matter of debate, but it certainly strikes me as unlikely.  For example, most of the US has had picture driver's licenses for decades, but the police still cannot stop me and demand that I show my driver's license or any other ID papers in a "Nazi-esque fashion."

Comment: @phoog I make know judgments about the veracity of the argument, just that it exists and causes controversy.

Comment: This answer is pointing out the controversial arguments...not whether or not they are valid arguments. +1

Comment: Re *"belief"* (to signify commonplace historic facts): that seems like a dodge to avoid *comparing* the relative weights of those facts.  (i.e. *beliefs* can be incommensurable, but *facts* needn't be.)

Comment: Re *"The controversy isn't about the laws themselves."*: that cannot be true, since many people dislike the voter ID laws.

Comment: @DrunkCynic: Sorry. The mobile app sometimes makes that a bit difficult to see. Will correct.

Comment: @phoog I think the terminology I see most often — or the one i remember, anyways — regarding that is “slippery slope”, or that people don't recognize big changes if done gradually and over many generations.  Such usage is dissimilar to the phrase used in describing a logical fallacy, where causality is assumed but not rigorously proved or investigated.

Comment: “those born as US citizens without documentation” How is that even possible? If you are a citizen of a country both you *and* the country need a way to prove it, and viceversa. A country cannot just say "I don't know if this person is a citizen or not".

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Ahh haven't seen much of the rural side of the US huh?:) I mean it's possible to get lost in the system even in much more regulated countries but in the US ending up without proof of citizenship is easier than most places I think.

Comment: @phoog:Re: but the police still cannot stop me and demand that I show my driver's license or any other ID papers
Many US states have "Stop and Identify" laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_and_identify_statutes

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: No one in the US is ever issued proof of identity or citizenship automatically.  Parents get their children a Social Security number when they hit about 2 (for tax reasons), if they pay taxes.  Immigrants are issued paperwork, but citizens are not.  If you don't decide to drive, there's nothing that forces you to get a picture ID.  I'm not even sure babies need to be registered in this country (our child was born before we immigrated).

Comment: @Flydog57 stop and identify requires a reasonable suspicion that a crime has been committed or is about to be.  I assume that "Nazi-esque fashion" implies a demand for papers without suspicion.  Certainly current fourth amendment protections applicable to the statutes you cite would continue to apply regardless of whether voter IDs are implemented.

Comment: @user1530 "What makes "Voter ID laws" so controversial in the US?"

Answer (score 29):

Your confusion is probably because the problem is not as straight-forward as it seems.

1. "Requiring an ID" - This was never about requiring an ID.  This is about requiring a very narrow group of photographic IDs, only. Need a government issued photo ID?  What if you don't have one, but have all the documentation needed to obtain one?  Not good enough.  So that's good enough to get the photo ID, but not to substitute as one.

   In many municipalities you used be allowed to supply a lesser form of photographic ID, along with other documentation, in combination.  That's not accepted under these laws.
2. Which IDs are OK?  Driver's licence is fine.  Passport is fine.  Not everyone can easily get these, or there is a cost associated with them.

   College student IDs (tend to be more liberal in voting habits) - no good in many states.  Gun permit?  Good.  A VA card, used to collect federal veteran benefits?  Not accepted under many of the laws.  Clearly, it's not just about having "a form of ID" or even "a form of photo ID."
3. Everyone should have one, right?  Claims that you have to have one to collect benefits or open a financial account are meaningless.  I can open financial accounts online, without supplying a photo ID.  Many of the elderly may have had some of the IDs at one time, but no longer do (no longer drive, for instance), and established their benefits and financial accounts decades ago, and have been voting non-stop ever since.  Many of the elderly also no longer can get out and about like they used to be able to. Others, like members of religious orders, do not have those kinds of accounts, or drive, but, as citizens, should be able to vote.
4. It's easy to get, right? There are many groups of people who can't easily get a government issued ID.  Access to locations, especially in more rural areas, the need to have transportation to get to them, the ability of hourly minimum-wage workers to take time off when they don't have scheduling flexibility or paid time off, etc etc etc.  It doesn't matter if you deem it a minor inconvenience, or if it's a brick wall.  ANY requirement that creates a burden that falls specifically on a particular group or groups is going to have a skewed impact on elections.

   When Mississippi first instituted their voter ID requirements, you needed a birth certificate to get a valid, accepted photo ID.  If you didn't have a birth certificate?  No problem..... if you have the photo ID required to get one.  Oops.

   [State Facing Voter ID Hurdles](http://www.jacksonfreepress.com/news/2012/jul/05/state-facing-voter-id-hurdles/)

   Many poor, older, rural citizens were not born in hospitals and were never issued a birth certificate.  There was another case of a man in Wisconsin where there was a clerical error on his certificate (born in another state), so he could not get a photo ID, and the hurdles to getting valid documentation were enormously expensive and cumbersome.

   [Bill Moyers - Black man in Wisconsin brought three forms of ID to the polls and couldn't vote](http://billmoyers.com/story/a-black-man-brought-3-forms-of-id-to-the-polls-in-wisconsin-he-still-couldnt-vote/)
5. What's the history in the USA regarding obstacles to voting?  In the days of institutionalized racism via [Jim Crow and other laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Crow_laws), there were [poll taxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poll_taxes_in_the_United_States) or fees to vote, which blocked the poorest from voting, and arbitrarily administered ["literacy" or civics tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disenfranchisement_after_the_Reconstruction_Era#Educational_and_character_requirements) where a white voter might, say, get asked to recite the Pledge of Allegiance, and a black voter might get asked to name the Massachusetts delegates who signed the US Constitution.

   Today, those more likely to not have these forms of voter IDs, or have difficulty getting them come from demographic groups that tend to vote Democratic.  Coincidence?

   Those kinds of measures were deemed illegal obstacles, meant to prevent people from exercising their rights.  If you require someone who was never issued a birth certificate to have one, that is a process that can take months and can cost hundreds of dollars.  That's a de-facto poll tax.

   [Wikipedia article on US voter suppression, offered to illustrate the kinds of methods historically used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_suppression_in_the_United_States)
6. It's needed to address voter fraud, right?  - No, it's actually not.  While there are various kinds of illegal voting, or voter fraud that happens, the kind that would be stopped by a photo ID - in-person voter impersonation of a legitimate voter by someone else happens almost never, at all.  Voter fraud, because of it's one-by-one methodology, is almost impossible to tip any election unless there was a massive, coordinated effort of many, many, many people.  That is not the case.  Now, ELECTION fraud is a real threat, but that is not addressed by voter ID laws.  In fact, voter suppression of legitimate voters would be considered election fraud, by most measures.

   This is a solution in search of a problem.  In lawsuits challenging voter ID laws in many states, and definitely in Pennsylvania and Wisconsin, supporters of those laws admitted, in court, that they could not find even a single instance of this kind of fraud.

   [Ahead of trial, Pennsylvania admits there is no voter fraud problem](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/plum-line/post/pennsylvania-admits-it-no-voter-fraud-problem/2012/07/24/gJQAHNVt6W_blog.html)

So, when you look at the fact that requiring a narrow subset of IDs that CAN BE more difficult for some demographic groups to get vs others, to address a problem that does not exist, what you have is a targeted attempt to make it harder for some groups to vote.  It's 100% a voter suppression measure.

The argument that "hey, 99% of people should be able to get an ID" means that you are willingly disenfranchising 1% of the legitimate, legal voting population for something that happens a handful time out of hundreds of million votes cast.  It does not make sense, if your goal is integrity.

[The Truth About Voter Fraud - Brennan Center study on voter fraud](https://www.brennancenter.org/publication/truth-about-voter-fraud)

Comment: Speaking of PA, the House Republican Leader was dumb enough to get caught on camera saying that enacting a voter ID law would help Romney to win the state. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuOT1bRYdK8

Comment: @jalynn2 - I was aware of that.  There's almost too much of those kinds of stories out there to include it all.  :D

Comment: On point 2: What does it take to get a gun permit compared to a college ID? How many background checks and validations are attached to the gun permit, compared to just enrolling at a college and being handed an ID? The two aren't apples to apples.

Comment: Not sure why a "background check" has anything to do with establishing that Joe B is Joe B.  It only establishes that Joe B does or does not have a criminal or civil legal paper trail.

Comment: Regarding Background checks:  ATF Form 7743 https://www.atf.gov/file/61446/download
Further, state dependent, there is also a proof of citizenship and residence required to get the gun permit. Anecdotedly, I know this to be the case for Washington, South Carolina, Missouri prior to the recent law, and Utah.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - I'm talking about concealed carry permits, not gun seller permits or gun sale background checks.  You are either confusing or conflating the two.

Comment: Depending on the state, a concealed carry permit can be used to bypass purchase background checks (WA), or the permit may be required to even own/purchase firearms (IL). For all the states referenced in the last comment, those were Concealed Carry Permits I either hold or have held. To the base point, it is logically inappropriate to compare concealed carry permits to college identification.

Comment: @DrunkCynic green card holders can get concealed carry permits, but they can't vote, so a concealed carry permit is like a college ID in at least one respect: holding one doesn't prove eligibility to vote.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - again, how does a process that looks into criminal background make something a better or worse regarding verification of identity, itself?  Almost all colleges use identity verification services for students to be admitted, and most students have to furnish other forms of identification to get their valid student photo IDs.  Sounds like you don't know much about what it takes to get a student ID.

Comment: @phoog Cite a state law that allows green card holders to get a concealed carry permit, with follow on evidence that the permit is the same as those issued to citizens.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Every concealed carry permit I've held required proof of citizen ship.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - a quick Google search shows that in many states non-citizens can concealed carry.  You are also making an irrelevant statement. Voter photo ID is irrelevant to eligibility to vote.  It only establishes identity, so one form establishing that vs another means nothing.  Eligibility is determined at the voter registration level. Photo ID only verifies identity.

Comment: @DrunkCynic most states (perhaps all) follow federal law in prohibiting possession of firearms by aliens who are in the US illegally or as a non-immigrant.  In other words, they mostly allow possession of firearms by green card holders.  This means that a concealed carry permit would not serve as a check on fraudulent voting by permanent residents.  (What you *actually* had to prove was therefore most likely that you were *either* a green card holder *or* a US citizen, and since you're not a green card holder, you proved that you were a US citizen.) States I actually checked include VA and WI.

Comment: @DrunkCynic as for follow-on evidence, an internet image search for concealed carry permits returns several images of which none indicates the bearer's citizenship.

Comment: Concerning (1) and (2), the question is not very detailed on what the OP meant, but at least this European is just as baffled how "requiring a very narrow group of photographic IDs, only" could possibly be controversial. Your paragraph (4) does clear that up a bit, though, by explaining that getting such an ID can be very cumbersome due to various obstacles/inconveniences that are somewhat specific to the US.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Did you get a chance to see agc's answer?  That addresses this conceptual disconnect between US and European perspective very well.

Comment: Many commenters seem to be arguing that the correct photo ID somehow implies citizenship.  Voter ID laws don't use the ID to establish citizenship (Permanent residents can get REAL ID drivers licenses, military IDs and in some states gun permits).  Photo IDs establish identity only (well, and so extent, the bearer's address).

Comment: It's also worth noting that in some cases, strict photo ID rules were often accompanied by "cost saving" policies that resulted in closures of government id-issuing locations, often disproportionally in minority areas.  Take a look at Alabama:
https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2015/10/will-closing-alabama-dmv-offices-affect-black-voters/433089/
Politics can be fierce, but when it attacks a citizen's franchise, it's just wrong.  If it attacks the franchise of a particular group, then it's worse.

Answer (score 13):

There are several other excellent answers here, but let me try to boil it down:

## 1. Voting is a constitutional right.

This is *the* central point, and one I didn't see mentioned in other answers. You can't compare it to needing ID to drive or board a plane, since those aren't guaranteed in the constitution:

> **15th Amendment (1870)**: The right of citizens of the United States to vote **shall not be denied or abridged** by the United States or by any State **on account of race, color, or previous condition of servitude**.
>
> **19th Amendment (1920)**: The right of citizens of the United States to vote **shall not be denied or abridged** by the United States or by any State **on account of sex**.
>
> **24th Amendment (1964)**: The right of citizens of the United States to vote in any primary or other election for President or Vice President, for electors for President or Vice President, or for Senator or Representative in Congress, **shall not be denied or abridged** by the United States or any State **by reason of failure to pay any poll tax or other tax**.
>
> **26th Amendment (1971)**: The right of citizens of the United States, who are eighteen years of age or older, to vote **shall not be denied or abridged** by the United States or by any State **on account of age**.

The 1965 [Voting Rights Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_Rights_Act_of_1965#Provisions) adds additional specific provisions about what states can and cannot do with local voting laws and practice.

US courts have allowed some Voter ID laws, and struck down others as a violation of the constitution or of the voting rights act:

- [Supreme Court upholds Indiana law requiring photo ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crawford_v._Marion_County_Election_Board)
- [A federal appeals court has overturned North Carolina's sweeping voter ID law, ruling that the law was passed with "discriminatory intent" and was designed to impose barriers to block African-Americans from voting.](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/07/29/487935700/u-s-appeals-court-strikes-down-north-carolinas-voter-id-law)
- [Judge Throws Out Challenge To Alabama Voter ID Law](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2018/01/10/576868379/judge-throws-out-challenge-to-alabama-voter-id-law)
- [Texas voter ID law was designed to discriminate, judge rules](http://www.cnn.com/2017/04/11/politics/texas-voter-id-law-discriminate/index.html)
- [Appeals court upholds Virginia’s voter-ID law](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/public-safety/appeals-court-upholds-virginias-voter-id-law/2016/12/13/3888f46e-c150-11e6-9a51-cd56ea1c2bb7_story.html?utm_term=.4ef60a03e2e8)

Lots of further detail that I won't get into here, including [the distinction between "disparate impact" vs "disparate treatment"](https://www.heritage.org/election-integrity/report/disparate-impact-and-section-2-the-voting-rights-act) and the [2013 Supreme Court ruling that invalidated portions of the Voting Rights Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelby_County_v._Holder) which led to a wave of new Voter ID laws, but understanding the importance of this issue from a constitutional basis is an important place to start.

## 2. Millions of US citizens don't have a government-issued ID.

Some estimates suggest that [over three millions Americans don't have a government-issued photo ID](https://www.npr.org/2012/02/01/146204308/why-millions-of-americans-have-no-government-id):

> The most common form of government-issued ID are driver's licenses and so the people who are most unlikely to drive, as it is, is elderly, the poor, people who live in big cities, like African-Americans, especially young people, too, especially if they attend college. They may not have need for a car at the moment.
>
> And then people who are in rural areas. The other challenge for them is they are not near the Department of Motor Vehicles offices, etc., etc. where you would get these IDs.

Well, can't all these people just *go get* some ID? Some can, others cannot (from the same article above):

> Many of them never had birth certificates to begin with, and if they did, they were incorrectly - their names were incorrectly put onto these documents. And if that's the case, then you're not going to get an ID. They will not accept discrepancies between your birth certificate and other forms of ID that you may have, like a Social Security card and those kinds of things.

Lots of other stories that emphasize the fact that getting ID is much more difficult if you are [elderly, or poor, minority, or don't have reliable transportation](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/courts_law/getting-a-photo-id-so-you-can-vote-is-easy-unless-youre-poor-black-latino-or-elderly/2016/05/23/8d5474ec-20f0-11e6-8690-f14ca9de2972_story.html?utm_term=.7b693f4a6040).

Some state's laws do attempt to provide better methods for people who don't have them to get IDs, or provide ways for voters to cast "provisional" ballots if they can't obtain ID.

## 3. The US has a long ugly history of disenfranchisement and voter suppression

Read up on [Jim Crow laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Crow_laws), including [poll taxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poll_taxes_in_the_United_States), [literacy tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literacy_test) and [grandfather clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_clause#Origin).

Opponents argue that Voter ID laws (and other practices [like voter roll purges, polling place indequalities, and DMV office closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_suppression_in_the_United_States)) are a modern form of voter suppression.

**So, is that a plausible argument? How would Voter ID laws disenfranchise certain groups of voters?**

If the percentage of citizens *without* ID were evenly distributed throughout the population (when measured by party, by race, by age, by gender, or by income), then no, Voter ID laws would impact all those groups the same.

But is that the case? No.

- In 2012, (then) Attorney General Eric Holder quoted studies claiming that "[nationally, only 8 percent of white voting-age citizens, while 25 percent of African-American voting-age citizens, lack a government-issued photo ID.](http://www.politifact.com/texas/statements/2012/jul/11/eric-holder/eric-holder-says-recent-studies-show-25-percent-af/)". Politifact rated this statement "mostly true".
- [College Students are frequently disenfranchised by voter ID laws](https://thinkprogress.org/students-are-being-rejected-from-the-polls-because-of-north-carolinas-voter-id-law-5b7b3f7b8caa/).
- As discussed above, [obtaining ID is more difficult if you are elderly, poor, minority, or don't have reliable transportation](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/courts_law/getting-a-photo-id-so-you-can-vote-is-easy-unless-youre-poor-black-latino-or-elderly/2016/05/23/8d5474ec-20f0-11e6-8690-f14ca9de2972_story.html?utm_term=.7b693f4a6040).

So no, different groups are *not* equally impacted by Voter ID laws. Those in lower income brackets, minorities, and college students are three demographics that are disproportionately impacted, they also tend to vote disproportionately Democratic.

Is it coincidence, then, that more Republicans than Democrats tend to support restrictive Voter ID laws?

The statistics by themselves are no smoking gun, of course. But [some Republicans have been a little less circumspect about deliberately attempting to tip the scales](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/17/us/some-republicans-acknowledge-leveraging-voter-id-laws-for-political-gain.html):

> Representative Glenn Grothman, Republican of Wisconsin, predicted in a television interview that **the state’s photo ID law would weaken the Democratic presidential candidate Hillary Clinton’s chances of winning the state** in November’s election...
>
> In Florida, both the state’s former Republican Party chairman, Jim Greer, and its former Republican governor, Charlie Crist, told The Palm Beach Post in 2012 that **the state’s voter ID law was devised to suppress Democratic votes**.

From the same article, a staffer relays what happened during a Wisconsin Republican caucus meeting:

> "I was in the closed Senate Republican Caucus when the final round of multiple Voter ID bills were being discussed. A handful of the GOP Senators were giddy about the ramifications and literally **singled out the prospects of suppressing minority and college voters**. Think about that for a minute. Elected officials planning and happy to help deny a fellow American’s constitutional right to vote in order to increase their own chances to hang onto power."

## 4. Are more restrictive Voter ID laws necessary to ensure the integrity of elections?

To be clear, this isn't just about *whether* some form of identification should be required to vote, this is about efforts to *narrow* the types of IDs that are acceptable. [This page has a good timeline of voter ID laws in the US](http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/voter-id-history.aspx), this chart is a nice summary:

[image: Voter ID Enactments 2000-2016]

I'm not going to through the differences between *all* these categories (they vary widely by state anyway), but it is worth discussing the two least restrictive ones:

- **No ID Required**: The voter is still typically required to find their name in the pre-printed registry and sign, under penalty of perjury, that they are who they say they are.
- **Non-strict, non-photo**: If the voter doesn't have picture ID, they can show a utility bill with their name and address, or perhaps a voting reminder card send from the state.

It is worth stopping here and asking the question: *are these measures sufficient?* Have there been vast number of people swearing, under penalty of perjury, that they are someone else? Do people routinely print fake utility bills on their home computer just so they can go vote more than once?

Overwhelmingly, the research says **no**, [in-person voter impersonation is almost non-existent](https://www.brennancenter.org/analysis/debunking-voter-fraud-myth). This 2012 report found a [whopping 10 cases of in-person voter impersonation since 2000](https://votingrights.news21.com/article/election-fraud/).

**But that's 10 more cases than there should be, right???**

Perhaps, but should we disenfranchise [millions of voters](https://www.npr.org/2012/02/01/146204308/why-millions-of-americans-have-no-government-id) all to prevent these 10 cases?

*That's* why Voter ID laws are controversial.

Comment: You've misused the 'grandfather clause' claim; it was installed as an exemption from the poll taxes and literacy tests, to keep the white people who couldn't satisfy those metrics able to vote.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I see, they were used in conjunction. Thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: " in-person voter impersonation is almost non-existent. " This reminds me of  Justic Scalia's famous statement, "It should be noted at the outset that the dissent does not discuss a single case -- not one -- in which it is clear that a person was executed for a crime he did not commit." Once someone is executed investigations usually stop, so of course they weren't finding evidence to exonerate the already convicted. Similarly, we don't find voter fraud when we refuse to look for it. How do we know there is no fraud when we are denied the tools we need to have in order to recognize it?

Comment: @Readin So to some degree I acknowledge your point, that, by definition, we don't know all the times someone *got away with it*, but notwithstanding the baseless claims of our current president, in-person voter fraud isn't even seriously *suspected* in any large numbers. [This comprehensive investigation](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2014/08/06/a-comprehensive-investigation-of-voter-impersonation-finds-31-credible-incidents-out-of-one-billion-ballots-cast/) only found 31 *suspected* cases out a billion votes cast, even in states that had stricter voter ID laws.

Comment: @Readin and furthermore, you still have to weigh it against the cost - how many legitimate voters don't have the money, time, or enough other documentation to get their approved ID. Again, by any reasonable estimate: far, far more than any suspected fraud.

Comment: @BradC That's actually the larger problem with your answer. You're not trying to answer the question, you're trying to persuade people that voter ID is a bad idea. I mentioned a problem with one part of your answer to give you chance to clarify or rectify it. Instead you respond by saying that even if there is problem with that part of your answer, voter id is still a bad idea. As I understand it the purpose of politics.stackexchange.com is not to argue political points but to answer questions in an unbiased way.

Comment: @Readin The original question is, basically, "voter ID laws sound like common sense, what am I missing?" for which I've attempted to describe the practical, historical, racial, political, and statistical reasons why it isn't quite that simple. You don't have to agree, of course, but I think I've answered the question as posed.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer due to the most recent edit. If states can require an ID for individuals to exercise their rights as protected by the second amendment and 10th amendment, why not the right to vote? Arguments grounded in the concept of disparate impact are contentiously approached.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I wasn't suggesting that those amendments make *all attempts* at requiring voter ID unconstitutional - the courts have been pretty clear that they don't - but some *have* been struck down by courts as an infringement of voter's rights, and that couldn't have happened without the 15th/19th/24th/26th Amendments. I'll edit to try and make that more clear. In the same way the 2nd amendment limits the abilities of states to regulate guns, the 15th/19th/24th/26th Amendments limit what states can do around voting, and its up to the courts to determine if they've stepped over the line.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Edited, see if that is better worded.

Comment: I've countermanded my downvote, given the comparison over Voter ID Laws.

Comment: @Readin - So, going to the argument of "how can we find instances of voter fraud if we don't look for it?" - first I'd ask how you would look for that. However, if it existed, at all, it would be pretty easy to spot.  If Readin goes and votes, pretending to be me, that's going to be very easily identified as an issue when PoloHoleSet goes in to vote and they tell me I've already voted, or if I vote and Readin goes in claiming to be there to vote, and I've already cast my ballot. It's going to show up even if you don't actively look for it.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet unless I have the good sense to vote using the name of some yo know to be dead, suffering from dementia, or otherwise incapable of voting.

Comment: @Readin - feel free. But since it's not 1955 any more, and all states have legal requirements and processes in place for removing deceased voters from the rolls, you'll find reality does not match up with your overactive imagination. Over 60% of the states have the same in place for mental incapacitation. This simply does not happen. Penalties for doing so far outweigh the minuscule or non-existent benefit.

Answer (score 7):

> I hear that it is because obtaining an ID in the US in no simple matter, is it true?

What do you consider to be a simple matter?  Getting an ID can require proof of citizenship, usually a birth certificate.  Those who do not already have a copy of their birth certificate may have to pay a fee to get one.  A price of $30 has been asserted.

Note that an ID is also required to start at a job ([form I-9](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9) to prove identity; the I-9 also requires either proof of citizenship or proof of work eligibility for non-citizens).  Yet we rarely see complaints about that.

> What are the historical and political reasons that make the topic so controversial?

Historically, Southern states used [Jim Crow laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Crow_laws) to prevent blacks from voting.  In particular, they would create tests or fees which they would enforce more heavily on poor blacks than on whites.  In reaction, almost all such requirements have been prohibited.  It is generally illegal to charge a fee to vote.

Voter ID laws disproportionately restrict urban voters, who are much less likely to own a car and have a driver's license.  Urban voters are also more likely to be black.  Restrictions that have disproportionate impact on blacks create echoes of the Jim Crow laws.

The net result is that right wingers view ID as a perfectly reasonable requirement and think that it is silly not to require it.  But blacks (who almost universally vote for left wing candidates) feel like such requirements target them—with some historical justification.

Comment: `an ID is also required to start at a job (form I-9 to prove citizenship)` -> According to [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-9_(form)#Documentation_for_proof_of_identity_and.2For_employment_authorization) you can also use other documents. For example, a School I.D. + Social Security Card should also be fine for the proposes of the I-9 form.

Comment: Not a bad answer but has technical errors. An ID is not required to get a job. In general, there are more urban voters, but ID laws also greatly affect rural poor as well

Comment: @Cerpetsmoker in particular the I-9 form doesn't require proof of citizenship; it is for verification of employment eligibility. Being a US citizen is only one way of being eligible for employment, and of course the other routes to eligibility do not carry with them the right to vote.

Comment: Brythan: driver's licenses also do not require proof of citizenship.  The only IDs that require proof of US citizenship are passports (including passport cards) and enhanced DLs (which can substitute for US passports when crossing the land border).

Comment: You can register in some states with a water bill on-line.

Comment: RMVs as registration bodies makes sense only for spead-out areas where cars are common (and feasible).  Surely car drivers would be appalled if they were required to register for voter IDs in subway stations.

Comment: And yet, it was **Democrats** who insisted on coupling voter registration with drivers' licenses.  See the [motor voter law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Voter_Registration_Act_of_1993).  And that still doesn't address the question of requiring ID itself, only of providing access to ID.  Note that a passport is pretty universally accepted as an option and can be obtained from the *federal* government.  So if it were really an issue, the federal government could have addressed it directly.  Possibly in conjunction with the Democrats who control city governments.

Comment: "Voter ID laws disproportionately restrict urban voters, who are much less likely to own a car and have a driver's license." - could you elaborate on that a little bit, please? Especially in light of [@phoog's comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14500#comment50916_14500) above that claims: "I'm unaware of these laws being an issue in cities. Most of the coverage I've seen concerning disenfranchisement of poorer voters has covered the rural poor and their need to drive for hours to reach an office where they can get an ID." Maybe both statements are true somehow.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In both cases the problem is transportation, but the details are different. Poor in urban areas are generally more reliant on public transportation schedules and routes. DMVs in urban areas might be closer, but service a much larger population, so are busier and more difficult to service in a reasonable time. When you take into account changes to hours and even DMV closings in minority communities ([see Alabama](http://www.al.com/opinion/index.ssf/2017/01/as_it_turns_out_bentleys_drive.html)), it is hard to think it isn't deliberate.

Comment: Talking about blacks in rural areas only makes sense in the south's cotton belt.  In the north, blacks are overwhelmingly urban.  Beyond that, in rural areas, people need driver's licenses for reasons other than voting.  I've heard people make the rural claim before, but IMO it's more about access to services than voting.  It's urban areas where people can get along without a driver's license and where most of the black population lives in most states.

Comment: "*Those who do not already have a copy of their birth certificate may have to pay a fee to get one. A price of $30 has been asserted.*" -> I think this is the more shocking fact for my European (French) point of view. Article 15 of the declaration of Human Rights states that *Everyone has the right to a nationality.* Doesn't everyone have the right to get a paper proving his nationality ? https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Universal_Declaration_of_Human_Rights

Comment: @Brythan, Re: driver's licenses also do not require proof of citizenship
No, but "REAL ID" driver's licenses do require that you prove your immigration status (so, for citizens, they need to prove they are citizens).  Not all drivers' licenses need to be REAL ID licenses, but most REAL ID licensed states only offer the REAL ID variety.  A state could offer a less-than-real-id license, but the bearer couldn't use it to get on an airplane or enter a federal facility. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_ID_Act

Comment: @Evargalo That's your French point of view, not European.  As far as I know, France is the only EU country that issues free identity cards.  In the Netherlands, for example, they cost €51 if you live in the country or €118 if you live abroad.

Answer (score 3):

Capsule version, (see longer answers for more detail):

At present, US voter IDs are issued on a voluntary "*pull*" basis, (the prospective ID-less voter must somehow satisfy a local gauntlet of one or many bureaucrats, some of whom might be politically appointed, underfunded, or understaffed), the fallibility of which makes such IDs an excellent means of voter suppression... which, it is widely believed, consequently helped elect many unpopular office-holders.

Contrast such a system to a "*push*" system of IDs, (something an eligable citizen *cannot* avoid, as with draft registrations, taxation, censuses, *etc.*), in which various adequately funded public servants would seek and provide **all** eligible voters with a voter ID.  (A "*push*" system does not exist in the US.)

Answer (score 0):

You're right and your expression of surprise at our laxness in this regard is common among Europeans, in that almost the entire developed world requires voter ID, as [John Fund](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/421292/voter-id-other-countries-require) found:

> Almost all industrialized democracies — and most that are not — require voters to prove their identity before voting.
>
> The vast majority of countries require voter ID — usually photo ID — to prevent fraud and duplicate votes at the polls. Our neighbors do. Canada requires voter ID. Mexico’s “Credencial para Votar” has a hologram, a photo, and other information embedded in it, and it is impossible to effectively tamper with. Confidence in the integrity of elections has soared since its introduction in the 1990s.
> At a 2012 conference in Washington at which election officials from more than 60 countries met to observe the U.S. presidential election, most were astonished that so many U.S. states don’t require voter ID.

### Are IDs hard to get? The CONTROVERSY

The controversy is that Democrats believe that Voter IDs depress or suppress the black vote and harkens back to real suppression of the black vote under Jim Crowe laws.  The below is Barack Obama in his last press conference of his presidency (a few days ago)

> OBAMA: We are the only country in the advanced world that makes it harder to vote rather than easier *(Ed note: an obvious lie and rank demagoguery given the analysis by Fund)*. And that dates back. There’s an ugly history to that that we should not be shy about talking about.
> QUESTION: Voting rights?
> OBAMA: Yes, I’m talking about voting rights.  The reason that we are the only country among advanced democracies that makes it harder to vote is — it traces directly back to Jim Crow and the legacy of slavery and it became sort of acceptable to restrict the franchise. And that’s not who we are. That shouldn’t be who we are. That’s not when America works best. So I hope that people pay a lot of attention to making sure that everybody has a chance to vote. Make it easier, not harder.

The other side of the controversy: IDs are not hard to get, and that fraud is real:

Is it hard to get an ID?  Not really.  While I readily acknowledge that this video isn't statistically based (I will examine these in more detail below), it gives you a sense of the arguments through man on the street interviews, and it really is a good recap of what the controversy is about (note that the DMV is where US citizens get drivers licenses the most readily form of ID):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrBxZGWCdgs

Is voting fraud real? [Yes](http://www.americanexperiment.org/news/widespread-voter-fraud-documented-new-minnesota-supreme-court-case/)

> A new voter fraud case before the Minnesota Supreme Court claims 1,366 ineligible felons have cast at least 1,670 fraudulent votes in recent statewide elections, possibly tipping the outcome of close contests, including the 2008 U.S. Senate race.

The cast against voter fraud is usually that it is not statistically significant.  Tied to this is a whole cannon of argument on prosecution of these crimes, or lack thereof, the cleanup of voter roles, or lack thereof.  Voting fraud is a very broad topic for exploration.

Do voter IDs suppress black turnout? **Mixed.** The problem is that most voter ID laws were passed right when Obama was running, putting them to the test for the first time.  So you had two effects going on.  Note that the Obama effect won the [battle](http://www.politifact.com/punditfact/statements/2014/jul/17/jason-riley/black-voter-turnout-exceed-white-voter-turnout-eve/) and this is even after Obama getting numerous African Americans to the polls for the first time in 2008:

> The Census reports that in these states, black voter rates in the 2012 elections were just as high if not higher than white voter rates:
> Missouri: Black voter turnout higher by more than 6.0 percent*
> Tennessee: Black voter turnout higher by more than 6.0 percent
> Georgia: Black voter turnout higher by 0 to 5.9 percent
> Indiana: Black voter turnout higher by 0 to 5.9 percent
> Virginia: Black voter turnout higher by 0 to 5.9 percent*
> Arkansas: Voter turnout not statistically different*
> Kansas: Voter turnout not statistically different
> Texas: Voter turnout not statistically different*

Studies that indicate that IDs [suppress votes](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/govbeat/wp/2014/10/09/report-voter-id-laws-reduce-turnout-more-among-african-american-and-younger-voters/?utm_term=.76d85533c71a) or [don't](http://www.forbes.com/sites/neilassur/2015/06/15/can-voting-restrictions-impact-an-election-an-in-depth-look-at-a-divisive-issue/#572b8aa76a20)

One last point.  Most critics of voter Id laws point out most fraud is committed by absentee ballots.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52139/discussion-on-answer-by-k-dog-what-makes-id-laws-so-controversial-in-the-us).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52147/discussion-between-blip-and-k-dog).

Answer (score -4):

Because currently the system is easy for the entrenched powers to manipulate local election results.  As a result any support that either side would have that would actually lead to curbing abuse of the voting system is going to be controversial.

By itself voter ID laws will not do much of anything to curb the voter fraud that is going on.  But what it would do is make it possible to start tracking and documenting the actual amount of voter fraud that is going on.  The entrenched parties do not want that because they have systems in place to manipulate the results.

Any belief that the government is by the people and for the people in the US anymore is naive at best.  We have a government by the special interests and elite, for the special interests and elite.

Comment: This is a conspiracy theory rant.

Comment: If its just a conspiracy theory then why did hilary out perform bernie in several Dem machine areas that were polling pretty significantly in bernie's favor?

Comment: Why did trump win when he was losing every poll? Because polls aren't accurate indicators of actual votes.

Comment: @blip - Not asking about trump.  And there were polls that were accurate but because they included people that were not traditionally likely voters they were ignored.  But that is the general election I was askign about the primaries

Comment: Your claim is that elections results are manipulated and you have zero data besides polls. If polls are your data, than a lot of elections these days (including Trump) should be null and voided. But of course, that's silly, because polls are no proof of anything other than what some opinions of some random people are.

Comment: @blip that and the emails from DWS to Podesta admitting to the manipulation...  The manipulation happens.  It happens from both sides and neither side wants to surrender their advantages.

Comment: I'm not aware of vote manipulation in the Podesta emails. What is that in reference to, specifically?

Comment: You would have to ask DWS what she meant...

Comment: uhh...so, again, no *real* data...

Comment: funny how real life conspiracies, even those that have been shined a light on work.